# Firefox 57+ causes my MacBook Pro to shutdown

Tags: firefox, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

My Mac Book Pro Retina (MacOs 10.3) shuts down as soon as a I start Firefox - I'm using the Firefox Developer Edition. I think I started noticing this issue after upgrading to Firefox 57.

Sometimes the Mac shuts down as soon as the all the tabs have been opened on Firefox, which means I don't even get a chance to type anything in the address bar. First the screen goes blank, then the fan fires up and becomes very loud as if its running at Max rpm and then the mac shuts down.

I've also my Firefox configs and confirmed that I do not have any non-default config settings. I've experienced this issue even in Safe mode. Right now I'm typing this in Firefox after changing the number of Content Processes to 1 from 4 which was the default for my Mac and it seems to be holding up. I've tried to look through the Mac console logs and I haven't found anything that points me to why the Mac shutdown.

Has anyone else been experiencing this?

Comment: Would you consider filing a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=General)? That might help the devs figure out the problem ;)

Comment: To those folks that are flagging this question to be closed, would you please suggest a better stackexchange site that you think this is more appropriate for? I would gladly move it there. And I happen to get an answer or comment that suggests that someone was facing the issue. But it looks like it got deleted!

Comment: I didn't downvote but, if you filed a bug, would you consider linking it here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is happening to you that sounds super weird.

Do you have any third party ( non-Apple ) software running eg security software? For most systems running macOS and Firefox this should definitely not happen and does not happen for most people.

Comment: Nothing that I know of. I know this is totally weird which is why I posted it here to find out if anyone else is experiencing this.